# How to change the "cn" value to IP address instead of localhost in websphere Application server

Tags: ssl-certificate, websphere, ejb-3.0

I am trying to set up a client-server EJB using two different machines on my network. while installing WAS server it prompted me to add admin credentials, so LTPA is enabled (hope it enabled SSL). Now on client EJB deployed WAS server I have to configure the outbound IIOP SSL certificate(Correct me if I am wrong on this). But unfortunately in the server WAS admin console I can see SSL Signer certificates cn(Host/domain) parameter as localhost. the same "localhost" is arriving when I try to "retrieve from port" in client EJB WAS server.

I have attached the "Retrieve from port" screenshot

[Client WAS retrieve from port action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjjMp.jpg)

Even I have tried changing the hostname in the server WAS under the Server-> Communications -> Port to IP address instead of localhost.

I expect it should bring domainname.ipaddress

"Retrieve from port" action always brings "localhost" from the remote server

Comment: When you/someone was installing WAS, he set `localhost` as hostname during the installation. That resulted in generating SSL certificates using localhost name. If you want to change than, you will need to regenerate new certificates. Moreover it is recommended to use hostnames not IP addresses, as IP addresses may change. Look for some docs telling how to replace SSL certs in WAS for more info.

Comment: Hi Mate, As you suggested I can able to update by recreating the entries in sever side. but now i realise that my client WAS lookup is happening like this "Connection refused: connect Remote Host: 127.0.0.1  Remote Port: 9405". I have update the SSL certificate in client but it still lookup happens in 127.0.0.1 what am i doing wrong any guess ? 

Please add answer so that i can approve your

Comment: Your installation was done on localhost, so it in many placese will point to localhost or 127.0.0.1. I'd strongly suggest you just create fresh profile with your real hostname not the localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment by @Gas, I am following this below link

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tsec_sslreplacecell.html

will update in short